# New to C,Loop Issues

Tags: c

I want to enter value to my array and between 0 and 101 and trying to put zero or 101 will return an error but putting anything from 1-100 will allow me to enter a second number.

but i am stuck when  write code to add a second number the loop keeps going in 1 and i cant figure out my error. any help would be apreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
char letter;

int main() 
{
    int i;
    int grades[12] ;

    for ( i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
        do{//loops the following peice of code if values over 100 or less than 0 are entered 

            printf("Please Enter Grade 1:\n");
            scanf("%f", & grades[i]);
            if (grades > 100 || grades < 0)
                printf("Invalid Entry please enter another between 0 and 100:\n");
        }while(grades < 100 || grades > 0);
}
```

Comment: `%f` is for `float`, not `int`. Use `%d` for `int`.

Comment: ... and it should be `if (grades[i]> 100 || grades[i] < 0)` and `while(grades > 100 || grades < 0)`

Comment: You should check that `scanf()` actually read a value.  What you do if it doesn't is up to you, but options include gobbling the rest of the line and prompting the user once more, and terminating the loop(s).

Answer (score 3):

The mistake here is you're comparing the whole array to a value. What you want is *one element*, plus you need to test that you're outside of the acceptable bounds:

```
while(grades[i] > 100 || grades[i] < 0);
```

As Jonathan points out below, the logic in your code tests that it's within, which means only valid answers will loop forever, the opposite of what you wanted.

Comment: You show the condition `while(grades[i] < 100 || grades[i] > 0)`.  If I enter `-1`, that is less than `100`, so the loop continues; if I enter `101`, that is greater than `0`, so the loop continues; if I enter `50`, it satisfies both conditions, though only one is tested, and the loop continues.  You need `while (grades[i] < 0 || grades[i] > 100)`, don't you?  You're right that indexing is needed, but the condition also needs to be correct.

Comment: Yeah, inverting the logic here makes sense. Good catch. Edited accordingly.